# Continuous integration and deployment with several module developed with git-flow

Tags: github, jenkins, git-flow

I have 5 separate modules developed using git-flow workflow.
An additional module (still using git-flow) is used as a MQ module and enables all the modules to communicate with each other.
=> The project is made up of those 6 modules working together

I have set up a Jenkins integration server where some unit / functional tests are performed on the develop branch of each of the 6 modules (source of develop branch is retrieved from github prior to run the build). I have added an additional build that is used to perform integration / functional tests on the whole project. This last build is triggered each time a build succeed on one of the module.

My main problem is to know how to tag and deploy the project as a whole (list of tags from each module) once all the builds are successful.

Any pointer on good practises ?

Comment: I'm not using any orchestration tool. I was thinking of tagging each build and using an external script to release each module and deploy the project with the new created tags.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on the exact process you hope to implement, but I think you might like to check out the [promoted builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) plugin.  It will allow you to run one job (the "kick off downstream builds then tag then deploy" job), which runs some of its steps *only after downstream jobs have succeeded*.  If those conditional steps include tagging and deploying, then I think you've got what you need.

Another possibility is the [join plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin), but I think the promoted build plugin is a better match.